# How to assign values quickly in r

Tags: r

I want to run a partition regression in R, for which I need to assign a factor to indicate which partition this data belongs to. For example, when it is greater than mean+2 standard deviations,I assign the indicator 2, and between mean+1sd and mean+2sd, 1 so on and so forth. I know it can be done by if and else. But when the partitions are way too much, the code seems to be too long. Is there any easy and succinct methods to accomplish it?

```
   mean=mean(x)
   sd=sd(x)
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd< -3) signal[i]=-3
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd> -3) signal[i]=-2
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd> -2) signal[i]=-1
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd> -1) signal[i]=0
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd>1) signal[i]=1
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd>2) signal[i]=2
   if((x[i]-mean)/sd>3) signal[i]=3
 }
```

---

Thanks for @jogo and @r.user.05apr.
Now I have a slightly different problem. I want to compute the partition based on rolling windows, 20 days for example, which means I need to scale the data of day t based on the past 20 days (day t-20 to day t-1) and assign the same values as above according to its z score. In such case, can cut function still be used? I have written a code with a loop and if sentences

```
signal <- vector()
n=20  #window
for(i in (n+1):length(x)){
  mean=mean(x[(n-20):(n-1)])
  sd=sd(x[(i-20):(i-1)])
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd< -3) signal[i]=-3
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd> -3) signal[i]=-2
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd> -2) signal[i]=-1
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd> -1) signal[i]=0
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd>1) signal[i]=1
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd>2) signal[i]=2
  if((x[i]-mean)/sd>3) signal[i]=3
}
```

Comment: When you ask a question, get an answer that works for the question you asked, but you realize have another question, don't edit your question and "move the goalposts". Upvote and accept the answer(s), then ask a new self-contained question, linking back to your original question if need be.

Comment: I'd also recommend doing a little research on "rolling window" question - there are lots of questions and answers about rolling windows in R if you do a little searching. [Here's a search for "\[r\] rolling window function"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+rolling+window+function) with a lot of useful answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cut()`

```
x <- iris$Petal.Length
m <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)
cut((x - m)/s, breaks = c(-Inf, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, +Inf), labels = c((-3):3))
```

to coerce to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.character(cut((x - m)/s, breaks = c(-Inf, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, +Inf), labels = c((-3):3))))
```

#### remark:

You can shorten `(x - m)/s` to `scale(x)`

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how dynamic the value assignment has to be. Alternative option:

```
criteria <- data.frame(operator = c("<", rep(">", 6)),
                       criterion = c(-3, seq(-3, -1, 1), 1:3),
                       result = c(seq(-3, 0, 1), 1:3),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
criteria # data frame with individual conditions for if

get_signal <- function(mean, sd, x) {
  dummy <- (x-mean)/sd
  for (i in (1:nrow(criteria))) {
    if (do.call(criteria[i, 1], list(dummy, criteria[i, 2]))) res <- criteria[i, 3]
  }
  res
}
sapply(-5:10, function(x) get_signal(2, 1, x))
```